# Only allowing one checkbox to be checked for a userform

Tags: excel, checkbox, userform, vba

So I'm making a userform and I have to use make a group of mutually exclusive checkboxes or only allow the user to pick one. "But just use option buttons!" you cry. Two problems with that:

1. I already have a separate set of option buttons in the userform (I believe you can somehow group them to allow multiple sets but I am unfamiliar with how to actually do this).
2. My professor specifically wants checkboxes

so I attempted to solve this problem like this

```
If CheckBoxBar.Value = True And CheckBoxatm.Value = True Then
GoTo Here:
End If

If CheckBoxatm.Value = True And CheckBoxmmHg.Value = True Then
GoTo Here:
End If

If CheckBoxatm.Value = True And CheckBoxpsia.Value = True Then
GoTo Here:
End If

If CheckBoxBar.Value = True And CheckBoxmmHg.Value = True Then
GoTo Here:
End If

If CheckBoxBar.Value = True And CheckBoxpsia.Value = True Then
GoTo Here:
End If

If CheckBoxmmHg.Value = True And CheckBoxpsia.Value = True Then
GoTo Here:
End If
```

The here leads to a message box that re initializes the userform after the msg box says "You are only allowed to select one" with code like this

```
Here: MsgBox "You are only allowed to select on pressure unit."
```

The code "works" but it always goes to the Here: statement despite only picking one of the checkboxes. Can you spot anything wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have an `Exit Sub` in your code before the `HERE` label? If not the code after the label will still always execute. Aside from that, consider using `OptionButtons`, which only allow you to pick one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Doug Glancy in a comment, your current code is probably missing an `Exit Sub` before the label `Here:`, which is therefore allowing your code to fall into the section after the label.

Another way of achieving what you are after is just to have one `If` statement which checks if more than one `CheckBox` is checked, and then display the MsgBox if so, e.g. as follows:

```
If CheckBoxBar.Value + _
   CheckBoxatm.Value + _
   CheckBoxmmHg.Value + _
   CheckBoxpsia.Value < -1 Then
    MsgBox "You are only allowed to select one pressure unit."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Or you can rely on the `.Value` being the default property of a CheckBox and thus "reduce" that code to:

```
If CheckBoxBar + CheckBoxatm + CheckBoxmmHg + CheckBoxpsia < -1 Then
    MsgBox "You are only allowed to select one pressure unit."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Note:  This method won't work if the `.TripleState` property of the `CheckBox` is set to `True`.  (My thanks to Comintern for pointing that out.)

Comment: Thank you! The first part actually did not work but the second part (seems) to works (the rest of my code isn't working for one check box but works perfectly for two!)

Comment: Note that adding up numeric value of implicitly casting `CheckBox.Value` to a `Boolean` only works if `CheckBox.TripleState` is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the checkboxes act like option buttons if you override the click function and clear the other boxes (although you can also have none selected).

```
Private Sub CheckBoxatm_Click()
     If Me.Controls("CheckBoxatm").Value = True Then Call ClearOtherValues("CheckBoxatm")
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxBar_Click()
    If Me.Controls("CheckBoxBar").Value = True Then Call ClearOtherValues("CheckBoxBar")
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxmmHg_Click()
    If Me.Controls("CheckBoxmmHg").Value = True Then Call ClearOtherValues("CheckBoxmmHg")
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxpsia_Click()
    If Me.Controls("CheckBoxpsia").Value = True Then Call ClearOtherValues("CheckBoxpsia")
End Sub

Private Function ClearOtherValues(cb As String)
    Dim cbPressure() As String, i As Long
    cbPressure = Split("CheckBoxBar,CheckBoxatm,CheckBoxmmHg,CheckBoxpsia", ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(cbPressure)
        If cbPressure(i) <> cb Then Me.Controls(cbPressure(i)).Value = False
    Next i
End Function
```